# Using custom Caret in JTextField for accessibility

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, caret

I'm programming a Swing Application and I have a friend that read much the Bible. This app have searches by text or passage.

But my friend only can see *big font sizes* and *contrasted colors*.  I change the color of caret for the `textField` with `setCaretColor`, where the user input the text to search.

The caret show like a rectangle with the same *hight* of font, but the **width** is little and I think that my friend cans not see.

Is there any way for change the width of the caret for show more bigger?

Comment: Why not use the host platform's magnification feature?

Comment: The lookAndFeel seems not responds to changes of Windows's theme...

Comment: It is not the theme that @trashgod was referring to, it is the (Windows 7) Control Panel|Appearance And Personalization|..Display or ..Ease of Access Center/Make the computer easier to see/Turn on Magnifier.

Comment: On Mac OS X, it's in `System Preferences > Universal Access > Zoom`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen this example from the Oreilly Swing book that's floating all over the internet?  It seems you can customize the caret a lot.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Fanciercustomcaretclass.htm

Comment: That example is good, but I need another thing. I have seen in Microsoft Word one thing. If you have a little size of font, you have a caret with the same height of the font. The width caret not change when you change the size of font, only the height

Answer (score 4):

maybe there are three ways how I can reproduce `Caret` and selection in th `JTextComponents`

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;

public class TextFieldExample extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TextFieldExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField tfield = new JTextField(10);
        tfield.setText("default text");
        final JTextField tfield2 = new JTextField(10);
        tfield2.setText("default text");
        tfield2.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                tfield2.setCaretPosition(tfield2.getDocument().getLength());
            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
            }
        });
        JTextField tfield3 = new JTextField(10);
        tfield3.setText("default text");
        tfield3.setCaret(new HighlightCaret());
        panel.add(tfield);
        panel.add(tfield2);
        panel.add(tfield3);
        add(panel);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class HighlightCaret extends DefaultCaret {

        private final Highlighter.HighlightPainter unfocusedPainter =
                new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(new Color(230, 230, 210));
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean isFocused;

        @Override
        protected Highlighter.HighlightPainter getSelectionPainter() {
            return isFocused ? super.getSelectionPainter() : unfocusedPainter;
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelectionVisible(boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus != isFocused) {
                isFocused = hasFocus;
                super.setSelectionVisible(false);
                super.setSelectionVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                TextFieldExample textFieldExample = new TextFieldExample();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I test with this code and I see that the width of caret `rentangle` seems to be the same in all textfields.

Answer (score 3):

May be this could help
http://java-sl.com/tip_overwrite_mode.html