# disable select all highlights of jTextfield

Tags: java, swing

How to disable the select all highlights of textfield .

```
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CustomFocusListener implements FocusListener {

    JTextField jtextField;

    public CustomFocusListener(JTextField jtextField) {

        this.jtextField = jtextField;
    }

    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {

        jtextField.selectAll();

    }

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        jtextField.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
    }

}
```

current code just hides the content also...
anyone who help ?

Answer (score 2):

To change the text color and selection color of a JTextField, you can use these two methods:

[setSelectedTextColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectedTextColor%28java.awt.Color%29)

[setSelectionColor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setSelectedTextColor%28java.awt.Color%29)

But I would not recommend to do that if you plan on using different Look and feel.

Comment: @NoufalPanolan why do you call selectAll() in the first place then? I must be misunderstanding something.

Comment: When i traverse through the textfields i want to select all in focus gaind and unselect all when focus lost.

Comment: @NoufalPanolan OK, I get what you want now; you want to reset the selected text. Actually highlight and selection are two different things. Visually it may look similar but actually one thing is a selection of text (which produces a highlighting), and the other is simply a change of the default foreground/background colors for one or several area of the text.

Comment: this is possible from UIManager too +1

Answer (score 1):

1) `jtextField.selectAll();`

`Focus` is simple asyncronous, then logically this could be

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JTextField.selectAll();
    }
});
```

but works for me in this form

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JTextField.setText(JTextField.getText()); 
        JTextField.selectAll();
        JTextField..requestFocus(); //requestFocusInWindow() I can't see diff
    }
});
```

2) `jtextField.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();`

- don't to play with `Caret`, not with `Highlighter`, you have to override Document too, [I can't see reason to modify something](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10320131/714968)
- what wrong with `Caret` & `selection`

3) for `JTextComponent` is there `Document / DocumentListener`

Comment: Here read this, [Why requestFocusInWindow() over requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocus()). A NOTE from Java Docs "Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of requestFocusInWindow(boolean)."

Answer (score 1):

Just set

jtextField.setSelectionEnd(0); in the method  onFocusLost();

Answer (score 0):

This can be done more easily by just removing the highlighter with [setHighlighter(null)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setHighlighter%28javax.swing.text.Highlighter%29)

> Sets the highlighter to be used. By default this will be set by the UI
>   that gets installed. This can be changed to a custom highlighter if
>   desired. **The highlighter can be set to null to disable it**....

```
textField.setHighlighter(null);
```